# Heroku Rails App terminates immediately (SIGTERM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to simply get the basic Rails application going, just initializing an empty/default project and put it on Heroku.

However, no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the default "Welcome Aboard" page on Heroku. 
Everything works locally though.

It seems like the application is being terminated immediately after being pushed up to Heroku. I'm seeing something with SIGTERM and 'process exited with status 143'.

Here's Heroku logs:

```
2014-05-07T19:09:26.423194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=b0b3030f-8292-4f5e-ad40-8763f6503d1e fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:09:26.703179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=80608d62-5b9c-4c20-9450-3909c42a4042 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=51ms service=55ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:09:26.791689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=d4c54ded-b7fa-4535-ad66-47ca49dbd8c4 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:10:08.421266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=e21b204e-8d22-4f47-83a8-01ea4b00163e fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:11:45.398253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=c9c8c2e3-86f2-492d-b738-d7ed4427abd5 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:11:45.664341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=061df699-108d-4776-b6c0-9a32db8efd22 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=83ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:11:48.467737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/home host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=f884c580-3648-4bc5-913e-1a80d9563024 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:11:52.832857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/leads host=young-caverns-5100.herokuapp.com request_id=43807ebc-4e3e-48f6-b014-9198b8dba0b2 fwd="24.5.234.171" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-05-07T19:18:02.160375+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-05-07T19:18:05.171369+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:05] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870533+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870534+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870535+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870537+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870539+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870540+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870542+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870544+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870551+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870553+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870556+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870555+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870558+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870625+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:05] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-07T19:18:05.870698+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984386+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:6427
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984396+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984398+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984400+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-05-07T19:18:05.984402+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-07T19:18:08.381243+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:08] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
2014-05-07T19:18:08.381212+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-05-07T19:18:08.381705+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-07 19:18:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=53268
2014-05-07T19:18:08.432919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-07T19:18:05.271399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 53268 -e production`
2014-05-07T19:18:07.843876+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

I've looked at numerous other SO posts, attempt the fixes, but I'm not getting anywhere. It seems like other peoples' problems don't involve 'status 143' either.

I've tried changing to PostgreSQL in production, changing precompile-assets from 'false' to 'true', running db:migrate etc etc.

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the problem, but I downloaded Ruby/Rails/etc following [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) tutorial yesterday. I used Ubuntu around a year ago using VirtualBox and easily created the default application on Heroku for a class before. I don't get it's not working with my current setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like some things are different when using Rails 4.X with Heroku that I wasn't aware of.

Followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#local-workstation-setup) on Heroku's site. Worked out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this command on your console hope it will work

```
heroku restart worker.1
```

its seems something like this on console

```
80:~/Desktop/hospitality$ heroku restart worker.1 

Restarting worker.1 dyno... done
```